# FINDSTR to cut a string with starting and end delimiter

Tags: windows, cmd, split, findstr

I have a text file as below

```
### OS ###
Machine;Manufacturer;Model;Current User;OS;Version;Install Date
AMSLTP2;LENOVO;7829H63;INDIA\4044;Microsoft Windows 7 Professional ;6.1.7601;20130301155559.000000+330

### CPU ###
Model;SocketDesignation;Status;# of Cores;# of Logical Processors
Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2350M CPU @ 2.30GHz;CPU;OK;2;4

### Services ###
Service;State;Install Date;Install Path
AcPrfMgrSvc;Running;;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Access Connections\AcPrfMgrSvc.exe
AcSvc;Running;;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Access Connections\AcSvc.exe
```

I have to prepare a `csv` file for each section like for OS (`### OS ###`) then followed by a text till next section (`### CPU ###`) then extract the other one (`### CPU ###`) till (`### Services ###`) till the end.

I have as limitation that I have to use `CMD` commands only as writing a batch file for XP, Win 7.

Tried all combinations but can't extract the information required.

Comment: `cmd /V:ON /C for /F "tokens=1,2* delims= " %G in (33144110.txt) do @if "%G"=="###" (set "_outfile=33144110%H.csv") else (^>^> !_outfile! echo %G %H %I)` command could do the job (write each section to distinct `csv` file) for _given_ data example. However, I post it only as a hint in comment... Read `cmd /?`, `for /?` etc. and visit http://ss64.com/nt/...